# If $A$ and $A \cap B$ are in a $\sigma$-algebra, is $B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

If $A$ and $A \cap B$ are in a $\sigma$-algebra, is $B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra? I thought this was true, but I seem to be unable to prove it.

Comment: Not necessarily. Let $A=\varnothing$ and $B$ any set not in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there a counterexample when $A \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Sure: just take $A$ to be a non-empty set in the $\sigma$-algebra that is disjoint from $B$. In the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ you can let $B$ be any uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ with an uncountable complement and let $A$ be any countable subset of $B$.

Comment: Let A be any set in the $\sigma$ algebra. C any set not in it and $B=A\cup C$, therefore not in it.  $B\cap A=A$.

Comment: If $A$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra and $A\subseteq B$, is $B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra? If the answer to your question is yes, then the answer to my question must also be yes.